# Integer Linear programming formulation if then condition

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint-programming

I want to create constraints such that I can implement the following condition:

Let A be an integer variable >= 0 with an upper bound of 12

I want to introduce the following variable B also an integer:

`if A = 1 then B = 0 else B = A`

Comment: Have you looked at other questions in the [tag:integer-programming] tag, and the questions in the related list?  Have you looked at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51025/cast-to-boolean-for-integer-linear-programming and https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755 and  https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76549/755?  I suspect you'll find that the question is answered there.  Also please edit your question to indicate whether you know of an upper bound on A or not.

Comment: I checked all these topics but could not found a solution for this question. Most of the answers are about boolean variables and not integers, which makes it more complicated.

Comment: You need Boolean algebra http://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2015/08/22/ilp-part-1/ + multiplication https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2015/08/29/ilp-part-2/ + comparisons https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2015/09/12/ilp-part-4/ + conditional operator https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2015/10/17/ilp-part-9/ and you can do whatever you like.

Comment: The first question I linked *is* about integers.  The second also discusses about integers; see "cast to boolean".  There are also other questions in the tag that are about integers.  I suggest spending a little more time to read through that material and learn about the typical techniques used there, and I suspect that will give you some ideas how to handle your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

you can introduce a binary variable z verifying the following constraints :

- (A-1) <= 12*z
- z<= 0.5*A
- -(1-z)*12 <= B-A <= (1-z)*12
- -12*z <= B <= 12*z