# IP Programming - objective function ist not a function BUT a table

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint-satisfaction

Here is a short description of my problem:

Part of my objective function is not a regular function. Instead it's a table.

You can see a short extract here:

[image]

So if the height is smaller or equal to 300 and the length is  between 301 and 345 (including 345) the price is p2.

My first idea was to create a boolean variable:

[image]

So i can add sth like this to my objective function:

[image]

Next step is to create two other boolean variables, one for, wenn the height is matching row r, and one for the length:

[image]

So when both of them are 1, y_r is also 1:

[image]

But how do i create constraints that can switch h_r and l_r to 1 if they are fitting the row r ?

I found a smiliar question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/112799/greater-than-and-smaller-than-condition-in-integer-linear-program-with-a-binar), but its not quite it. I´m not sure, if I have upper and lower bonds and what they are if so.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: See comparisons in https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2015/09/12/ilp-part-4/ and boolean logic in https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2015/08/22/ilp-part-1/